# How to uninstall an application without removing the user data?

Tags: applications, uninstallation

The title says it all. Say I have an application, a game for instance. Which I wish to uninstall from my phone, and reinstall sometime in the future. However, I don't want my game save to be lost.

Is it possible to uninstall an app but to keep its data?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Eventually, simply uninstalling and reinstalling normally worked! Turns out data is saved this way or another.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't true for most apps. When you uninstall an app, everything in `/data/data/<packagename>` is [thrown away](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12320/is-the-data-associated-with-an-app-cleared-when-an-app-is-uninstalled). Maybe your app saved to a different location or has cloud saves.

Comment: @lunboks: Perhaps, but since it worked for me, I accepted it. It's clear that the better answer would be to use some sort of backup app, just in case, and it reflects by the answer with most votes :)

Answer (score 12):

## My technique

If you don't want to root your device, you can use [adb](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info) and `pm` instead.  These steps will be hard to follow unless you already are familiar with the use of command-line tools.

1. Install [adb](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info) on your computer, and set things up so that it can communicate with your device.  Don't forget to enable USB debugging on your device.  It's a big hassle to get adb working for the first time; the consolation prize is that you only have to do it once.
2. Use a USB cable to connect your computer with your device.
3. Use `adb shell` to connect to your device.
4. Use `pm list packages` to see a list of installed package IDs.
5. Use `pm uninstall -k` plus your package ID, to remove the package but keep your user data.

See also this [related post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/55798/re-install-app-without-losing-personal-data#55817).

Comment: CAUTION: `pm uninstall -k` leads to being unable to reinstall the app via play store or f-droid. Play store complains that "another user has already installed this app"

Comment: @oarfish:  I tried it on my own device (running Android 8 "Oreo") within the past few weeks, and Google Play Store reinstalled the app without any problem.

Answer (score 6):

Try this program [SD Maid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.thedarken.sdm&hl=en).

Open program, go to AppControl tab and click the app you want. There is an option called, "Remove app but keep its data".

Edit:

I'm not sure but it might require root.

Comment: Seems like the latest version of SD Maid do not have "Remove app but keep its data" option.