# Re-install app without losing personal data

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, installation, uninstallation

How do you re-install an app without losing personal data?

In this case its Plants vs. Zombies 2 that hangs when loading the game. I thought a re-install might solve the issue. But I don't want to need to redo everything I've done so far.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the following procedure you'll need [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) installed on your computer (if you're not already have that, see: [Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474/16575)). Alternatively, a terminal emulator app should do as well.

Android apps are managed by the "Package manager", which has a [command-line](/questions/tagged/command-line) interface called `pm`. So here's what you can do with it for your case:

```
# to use ADB, first get a command line
adb shell
# now tell the package manager to uninstall the app, but keep its data
pm uninstall -k com.YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME`
```

<sup>(Note this won't work with a terminal emulator app on device (at least with none I know of) except with root permissions, as "normal apps" lack the required privileges/permissions.)</sup>

Of course you have to replace `com.YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME` with the package name of the app you want to deal with. Easiest way to find that is visiting its page on Google Play, and take a look at the URL: the package name follows the `id=` parameter there. It's the `-k` parameter telling the package manager to keep the app's data.

Now, when you re-install the app, its data is already there (was not removed).

All this does not require root (at least as long as we talk about a user-installed app).

Comment: After one hour Iv'e managed to do what you wrote. It took some time as all about Android SDK was new to me. I managed to re-install the game, and the personal data seemed to be there. But unluckily the game would still not load. Only after I removed the personal data.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid of that. It still could have been the Dalvik cache being messed up, but then an update/re-install (without uninstall before) should have cured that (so the app's own data being messed up was the logical conclusion). But it was worth a try. And having ADB running from your computer gives you a bunch of other options (see the [adb tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info) for hints on that).

Comment: You must be root in order to uninstall an app.  To become root, you must either launch `adb shell` from a computer or else you must root your phone and use the `su` command.  If your phone is not rooted, a terminal emulator won't allow you to uninstall anything.

Comment: @unforgettableid have you tried it? On most of my devices, ADB doesn't run as root. Still, `pm uninstall` works *for user apps* (i.e. those you've installed yourself) – as my answer points out, quote: "as long as we talk about a user-installed app". Admitted, I didn't try with a terminal emulator but always use `adb shell` for things like that – so for that part you might be correct (I didn't verify), as ADB gets slightly elevated permissions. Terminal app would need the corresponding permission ([INSTALL_PACKAGES](https://android.izzysoft.de/catmin/applists/perms#INSTALL_PACKAGES)) for that.

Comment: @Izzy: My mistake. I experimented further. `adb shell` indeed lacks root privileges. But it _does_ get enough permissions to run `pm uninstall -k`. Still, my terminal emulator ([jackpal.androidterm](//play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm)) does _not_ have sufficient permissions to run `pm uninstall -k`: when I try it, `pm` gives me a "Permission denied" error. I did my testing in Android "Jelly Bean" 4.1.2.  I wonder if, on a newer OS version, [App Ops](//play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.findsdk.apppermission) could grant more permissions to my terminal emulator?

Comment: I doubt that, @unforgettableid – it's `adbd` which gets "elevated privileges" (which it e.g. requires for `adb backup`). Terminal is dealt with like a "normal app" – so unless it explicitly *requests* additional permissions, it won't get them.

Answer (score 1):

Android hasn't got function which you described. If you have root access on your phone, you can make a copy of folder `/data/data/com.xxx.xxx`, reinstall app, and overwrite generated folder by your copy.

Comment: Android has this function, even built-in ;) See my answer. Works without root.

Answer (score 1):

You can also just reinstall the APK file that already exists on the device. After an upgrade to Android 6 somehow default permissions like `android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` were lost, that is where this trick comes handy to discover the APK and reinstall it:

```
adb shell
shell@hammerhead:/ $ pm path com.stackexchange.marvin
/data/app/com.stackexchange.marvin-2/base.apk
shell@hammerhead:/ $ pm install -r /data/app/com.stackexchange.marvin-2/base.apk
        pkg: /data/app/com.stackexchange.marvin-2/base.apk
Success
```

Alternatively if you would like to reinstall a bunch of packages (`-3` for [third-party packages only](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/shell.html#pm)), you can parse the obtain the list of installed packages on the device and reinstall all of them with:

```
pm list packages -f -3 | cut -d: -f2 | cut -d= -f1 | while read apk; do pm install -r $apk; done
```

Comment: I will just add that now you must use ```cmd package list packages -f -3``` and that in that ```cut -d= -f1``` did not work for every package, as some paths include base64 padding (```=``` characters), but was able to use regex in a text editor to process the list, and then use ```cat``` with the last part of your one-liner.