# Transferring data from old android that doesn't have much space left

Tags: samsung, data-transfer

Since the old phone ran out of space I got a new one with 4x storage space. Now I'm trying to transfer all the data from the old one to the new one. Alas, data transfer fails because there's not enough space on the **old** device.

Aye! I am upgrading because the old phone doesn't have any space left, and the data transfer to the new phone fails for the same reason. IDK why the extra space is needed on the phone the data is being transfer **from**, which is the first question: why does android need that?

Now, the practical one. The suggestion on the screen doesn't really work either: one of the items I'm transferring, the Messages, is causing the transfer to fail even when no other items are selected. Could you suggest a way to transfer all that without any significant storage requirements on the device the data is copied from? Maybe some configuration parameter that would allow the data from the same category to be copies piecemeal in an automatic batch of smaller transfers?

[image: Failed data transfer]

Comment: Just making sure you've tried/considered deleting old 'Apps/Games' which store their data in the cloud from your old phone to clear up space and then re-download/sync those apps/games on your new device. Most likely the additional space is for data and metadata which needs to be compressed before transfer.

Comment: Via adb it would be possible to delete apps (APKs) without deleting their data. If you have some large apps (the app itself not it's data) this may be an option. https://android.stackexchange.com/q/55798/2241

Comment: copy and delete some large files/apps first - also adb backup will not require space on your phone.